While running a Blazor server application in Visual Studio, if I make markup edits, why can't I see them in the browser when I refresh?
I was under the impression if you make changes to the markup of your razor page, and if you save and refresh the browser, you'll be able to see the edits.
I'm running a Blazor server application in Visual Studio 2022, using .NET 8. My web application has dependent projects that were built using .NET 4.8 framework. Why am I not able to see my markup changes in Chrome?
Thanks in advance.

…how are you able to have .netfx4.8 dependencies in your .net 8 project?

Have you enabled "Hot reload" from within Visual Studio? If not, you can enable it from the main toolbar once your application is running in debug (normally it's next to the run button). Alt + F10 will also get you there.
You can also specify "Hot reload on file save" which means that file changes should reflect in your browser without needing to even refresh it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2022
